# Not able to access @@odata.nextLink while fetching booking using microsoft graph api

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-calendar

While calling microsoft graph api for calender events, I am able to get the booking, but I am not able to access @odata.nextLink"  Its giving me the below error.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "53abhbbcksbabcjnlkkmaclhabbcak1",
        "date": "2019-04-09T13:11:43"
    }
}
```